# How to display two layouts in one screen?

Tags: android

Is it possible to put tow layouts in same screen , showing the upper half from activity one in the top of the screen and showing the bottom half from activity two in the bottom of the screen ?

Comment: No, but there are Fragments for that : https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Answer (score 0):

> A [Fragment](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) represents a behavior or a portion of user interface in an Activity. You can combine multiple fragments in a single activity to build a multi-pane UI and reuse a fragment in multiple activities. You can think of a fragment as a modular section of an activity, which has its own lifecycle, receives its own input events, and which you can add or remove while the activity is running (sort of like a "sub activity" that you can reuse in different activities).